# Working with anxiety

Tags: student, anxiety

So, I 've always been anxious about my performance and fear of failure being the main bone I have to contend with. And to make matters worse, I've been diagnosed with ADD (eleventy years ago, and I'm in the progress of going through a very thorough re-assessment, because I'm not quite sure the diagnosis is correct). 
All in all not very helpful when you're working in high-tech software (i.e. robotics and computer vision) in a pretty high tempo (which is great) environment.

During the years I've tried many medications:

- First I thought sleep was the problem, so I had been on Temazepam for yearsssss, but I stopped it because this does not help the underlying problems in the slightest.
- I've been on Ritalin and dexamfetamine (adderall?), but when using Ritalin I just want to lock myself up in the house and count flowers on the wall and using dex just felt wrong. It does certainly help keep focus on tedious tasks, which I suck at, but it also kills creativity.
- I've been on Mirtazapine (for sleep) and Venlafaxine (for general mood), the result of Mirtazapine being adding 20KGs (44lbs) WHILST cycling 5k+ a year and going to the gym. Go figure.

Venlafxine (@75mg daily) doesn't really alter my mood and although I don't experience any (negative) side-effects I'm considering tapering off (of course with help of my GP and other care providers who are more specialised in this sort of matter). And no, I'm not depressed.

So for nothing really helped. Then I discovered (was prescribed) Xanax. What a revelation. I felt motivated and actually got lots of stuff done and the anxiety,poef, gone! A gift from heaven. I was put on 2x1 mg, but I found that a bit much. 
So now basically have a regimen. Apart from my day job as a dev, I'm also pursuing a masters degree in bionformatics (so: molecular biology, some basic chemistry, systems biology, differential equations, differential equations and from time to time some differential equations and differential equations. Did I mention differential equations yet?

Now combining this with a 40 hr job, regular sporting activities and a wife that needs attention is a task in itself as you could problably imagine (no watching the TV time sink helps).

Anyhow the crux is: today I have a day off for study, and I've found that 0.5 mg xanax disolved in a nice cup of tea and drinking it slowly helps me get over my inherent laziness and actually, really helps me get to work (and remember it ;)).

I don't use it every day, maybe 2-3 times in a row (days like these and sometimes in the weekend), but I do feel it might be a bit sketchy to do so. It just puts me over the edge of giving in to slacking. And I can also easily, without side effects not take it for a week, or 2.

I usually don't drink alcohol, perhaps some red wine during the holidays on when we're on vacation.

So the real question is: I use these anxiolytics to actually focus on study and I'm kind of in dubio, the medication scares me, because it's so good and I really don't want to be a benzo addict... Should I keep doing it. Anyone else in the same boat here? Somehow it just doesn't feel right using this, while at the same time I acknowledge their helpfulness.

Comment: This is a good question, but it's a little challenging for us to answer in this kind of a format because it's hard for us to know enough about the particulars of your situation. Have you discussed your concerns with your doctor?

Comment: Also, FWIW procrastination and anxiety do often go hand in hand (because if you're really anxious about the task you'll also tend to want to procrastinate it). For me personally I found that, when I got treatment for my anxiety, I found it much easier not to procrastinate. I did work with a therapist too though (not just take medication) - I definitely recommend seeing one if you don't yet because that was actually more helpful to me than even the medication was.

Comment: I'm afraid my recurring prescription will de stopped. I don't have panic attacks or agoraphobia. My thinking is: why should I be allowed to take dex or ritalin, while they both make me feel like, well, crap and aren't really helpful. And i'ts not like I binge them away, heck I use less then prescribed, jut for an off-label purpose :)

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica Yeah, Feb 27th I'll be having a day long session with psychiatrists, psychologists, coaches etc, I explicitly asked for a CGT angle, and keep the meds for emergencies. Maybe helpful to say: I incorporated mindfulness practice into my daily life and like I mentioned I exercise quite often (i.e. 100+ mile cycling, noobie powerlifting, judo, BJJ)

Comment: Yeah, those things are helpful. CBT was great for me too, it really helped me improve my thinking patterns and have more confidence in myself. Personally I also took an SSRI for awhile for the anxiety, but mostly to help me work on stuff in therapy (I was doing fairly intensive OCD treatment at the time and felt at the time that it would've been too difficult without the medication). Obviously everyone's situation's different though.

Comment: I'm really afraid bad leads to worse. I've tried a relative high dose of Xanax once, but that just resulted in a tot black out. But these low doses, spread over time, really seem to help with studying, or getting to study. I'm not so afraid to make errors, so I'm not held back by endless doubt and actually progress pretty good (and remember it).Perhaps best keep a close watch and have a long chat about it the 27th

Comment: Hi. Fellow ADD here, and fellow imposter syndrome victim. @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica while anxiety surely impacts procrastination, it must be noted that ADD/ADHD people have a huge difficulty with the act of planning itself, together with an impaired sense of time. So procrastination is an effect of all this.

Comment: Your psychiatrist is not your enemy. You don't need to fool them or keep secrets from them to live your best life. Tell them your findings! Work *with* them to find a healthy medication regime. I understand the guilt surrounding being persistently medicated. That guilt is not useful within the context of your work with your psychiatrist.

Comment: And if you don't feel comfortable working openly and honestly with your psychiatrist, find a new psychiatrist. And if you don't feel comfortable working openly and honestly with *any* psychiatrist, figure out why and fix it.

Comment: Welcome to the site Pieter. I've placed this on hold given that a lot of the points raised here are not really topics we can or should cover here. I see a potential on-topic question concerning the (long-term) use of "performance enhancers" (regardless of reason) in the workplace but we can't really comment on your specific situation let alone recommend medication to help you. That's really a matter for a medical professional.

Comment: Xanax is not the kind of medication that should help you focus or feel motivated unless you have such severe anxiety that it is directly inhibiting your ability to function.  Which if that's the case you need to see a specialist and address your anxiety and not medicate in the way you are currently, it's a slippery slope and you're already on it.  As for A.D.D. - there is nothing wrong with using dextroamphetamine for it as long as you actually have A.D.D. and not just a case of "I don't like doing things that aren't fun".  A.D.D. is a chemical imbalance and adderall fixes that.

Comment: Trust me, I don't take dex for fun. I don't like uppers in the slightest. They make me feel out of touch (but calm) and weird and only help in cases of really tedious grunt work. Next Tuesday I have day long appointment to re-asses this diagnosis and hope to bring home some tools (apart from exercise and mindfulness practice).

Answer (score 2):

Fellow ADD here with a lot of struggles in the workplace because of that. I think that this is simply **the wrong place to ask**.

I would say that, as long as your medication regime is **fully followed by a proper therapist in a proper therapy setting**, you should do it if it makes your life better.

Actually, there is even **no real question**, as what I see is that you found a way to medicate but you can't frame it emotionally and have lingering feelings of guilt for doing this: another reason to ask to a therapist about how to deal with this.

(On one side, it seems also that you have quite a lot on your shoulders: a regular job, family, and studies. This can be a huge source of stress, especially if you are a pathologically wrecked planner as almost every ADHD person is.)

Comment: Yeah, the thing is, when I'm using these scarcely I have absolutely no issues with planning and I feel waaaay more confident. The meds are prescribed by my GP & psych. Dex just makes me just really anxious + I hate uppers yes, I'm one of those backard devs that doesn't drink coffee ;)). These factors are most of the reason why I want to re-assess my diagnosis of ADD.

Comment: @PieterHendriks just keep in mind that it's a spectrum and can manifest itself differently among people; but yes, a reassessment can be reasonable.

Comment: Addendum, thi answer really strikes into the heart of the matter, sadly I can't upvote yet. Of course I will be open and honest with my care providers and am very anxiuous ;) to hear their take on it :)